# Getting the date to show in a textbox on a button click

Tags: javascript, asp.net

The button is called "generateid" the textbox is called "generateidtxt" I want the date to show up in the textbox when I click on the button, but it is showing undefined.

```
    function Month() {
        var m = new Date();
        var mm = m.getMonth() + 1;
        mm;
    }
    function Year() {
        var y = new Date();
        var yy = y.getFullYear();
        yy;
    }
    function Day() {
        var d = new Date();
        var dd = d.getDate();
        dd;
    }


//generate id
    function guidGenerator() {

        var theID = (Year() + Month() + Day());
        theID;

}

function generateID() {

        var TheTextBox = document.getElementById("generateidtxt");
        TheTextBox.value = TheTextBox.value + guidGenerator();
    document.getElementById("generateid").disabled=true;    

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not returning anything in your `guidGenerator()` function:

```
function guidGenerator() {
    var theID = (Year() + Month() + Day());
    return theID;
}
```

Same with all your other functions:

```
function Month() {
    var m = new Date();
    var mm = m.getMonth() + 1;
    return mm;
}
function Year() {
    var y = new Date();
    var yy = y.getFullYear();
    return yy;
}
function Day() {
    var d = new Date();
    var dd = d.getDate();
    return dd;
}
```

Comment: ah Okay thank you. var theID = (Year() + "-" + Month() + "-" + Day()); returns 2013-6-13. Is there anyway I can code the middle number like 01 for january and 02 for feb and 12 for december?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're missing a return in `guidGenerator()` and all of your other functions:

```
    function guidGenerator() {

        var theID = (Year() + Month() + Day());
        return theID;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

None of your functions actually return a value. Use the `return` keyword:

```
function Month() {
    var m = new Date();
    var mm = m.getMonth() + 1;
    return mm;
}
```

By just doing:

```
mm;
```

All you are doing is evaluating `mm` and doing nothing with the result, which serves no purpose. It is syntactically OK but it's pointless.